# Compare two numbers in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Write a Bash shell script “order.sh” that takes two integer arguments “a” and “b”, and prints out the appropriate relationship “a < b”, “a == b” or “a > b” (with “a” and “b” replaced by their values).

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "enter the first number:"; read x
echo -n " enter the second number:"; read y

if ["$x " -lt "$y"]
then
echo "$x < $y"
else
echo"$y < $x"

if [ "$x" -eq "$y"]
then
echo " $x == $y "

fi
```

i am not being able to compile his code as it is failing and says "/bin/sh: make command not found"
can someone tell me what this means? i am new to shell scripting and i have no idea what is the problem...

Comment: Try `whereis bash` command

Comment: `www.shellcheck.net/` is your friend. Among other problems, you'll find that you need a space after `[` and before `]`

Comment: MO, when something does not work in bash, you can enable debugging output by calling your script with `bash -x scriptname`. That, in addition to the normal errors you must be seeing, will show you line-by-line the operation of your script printed to `stdout` (the screen). If for some reason bash is not in your `PATH` then it is generally in `/usr/bin/bash` (on most unix/linux type systems). If you are using `mingw/msys` on windows, read the `mingw` installation instructions for setting the path and environment. What OS are you running on?

Answer (score 3):

> i am not being able to compile his code as it is failing and says "/bin/sh: make command not found" can someone tell me what this means? i am new to shell scripting and i have no idea what is the problem...

Several problems in that statement:

- "compile this code" ... a Bash script doesn't need to be compiled. Bash is an interpreted language
- "/bin/sh: make command not found" means exactly what it looks like: the `make` command is not found. You don't have a `make` command on your `PATH`. But it doesn't matter, because you don't need `make` here

---

Your script has syntax errors, for example:

> ```
> if ["$x " -lt "$y"]
> ```

You need to put a space after `[` and before `]`, like this:

```
if [ "$x " -lt "$y" ]
```

Other problems:

- Not using `if-elif-else` for the 3 cases
- Broken conditions: there are 2 `if` but only 1 closing `fi`

---

A few other tips:

- For doing arithmetic in Bash, use `((...))` instead of `[...]`.
- Instead of `echo -n; read`, use `read -p`: it's one command instead of two, and the flags of `echo` are not portable, so it's better to avoid using them
- Indent the content of `if-elif-else` to make the script easier to read

With the corrections and improvements applied:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -p "enter the first number: "
read -p "enter the second number: "

if ((x < y)); then
    echo "$x < $y"
elif ((x > y)); then
    echo "$y < $x"
else
    echo "$x == $y"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `/usr/bin/env` to find `bash`. I think you also wanted an `elif` (and an `else` - your current one is missing a `fi` and won't test for greater than), and you should be using `[[` and `]]` (also you missed a space with `echo"$y < $x"`). Something like,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo -n "enter the first number:"; read x
echo -n "enter the second number:"; read y
if [[ "$x" -lt "$y" ]]; then
        echo "$x < $y"
elif [[ "$x" -gt "$y" ]]; then
        echo "$y < $x"
else
        echo "$x == $y"
fi
```

Which I tested, and does as you would expect. I suggest you see [7.02. More advanced if usage - Bash Beginner's Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html)

Comment: Why not `read -p` instead of `echo; read`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. what would be the difference between read -p and read x?

Comment: `read -p "Enter something: " line` provides a prompt string; it's pretty much the same as `echo -n "Enter something: "; read line`, but in just one statement, and the prompt is only displayed if input comes from a terminal (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins)).